# What is "Native method not found" bug with OpenCV in api 19?

Tags: android, opencv, android-api-levels

I have implemented **openCv** in my android project, project runs on device with **api 23**, correctly.

But just this project crashed on device with **api 19**. caused by:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:
>   org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()J

so the question is, **api 19** cant support openCV? 
or
**api 19** have a different config for openCV?

this is main part of my project:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
}

public void medianFilter(View view) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false; // Leaving it to true enlarges the decoded image size.
    Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test, options);

    Mat img1 = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(original, img1);
    Mat medianFilter = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, medianFilter, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);

    Imgproc.median(medianFilter, medianFilter, 9);

    Bitmap imgBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(medianFilter.cols(), medianFilter.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(medianFilter, imgBitmap);

    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.opencvImg);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of more description of code where you've called `medianFilter()` could've been more informative, but as per the code you've mentioned.

I'd suggest to form your code as below in  `onResume()`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

**Adding to the answer which i gave before**

I'll try to consolidate below whatever i've tried to resolve this:

I tried to do some tricks with `LoaderCallbackInterface`:

```
public class LoaderCallBackHelper: Java.Lang.Object,ILoaderCallbackInterface
    {
        public void OnManagerConnected(int p0)
        {
            switch (p0)
            {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.Success: 
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Success");
                    break;
                default:
                    this.OnManagerConnected(p0);
                    break;
            }
        }
        public void OnPackageInstall(int p0, IInstallCallbackInterface p1)
        {
            p1.Install();
            System.Console.WriteLine(p1.PackageName);
        }
```

Then something like this(on MainActivity):

```
    ILoaderCallbackInterface t = new LoaderCallBackHelper();
 public  MainActivity()
        {
            if(OpenCVLoader.InitAsync(OpenCVLoader.OpencvVersion3000,this,t))
                {
                System.Console.WriteLine("OK");
                }
        }
```

The issue still didn't resolve.

Then i tried some trick with

```
  public class BaseLoaderHelper : BaseLoaderCallback
    {
        public BaseLoaderHelper(Context context):base(context)
        {
        }
    }

        BaseLoaderCallback _t = new BaseLoaderHelper(this);
if(OpenCVLoader.InitAsync(OpenCVLoader.OpencvVersion3000,this,_t))
                    {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("OK");
                    }
            }
```

Still got the same error you've received.

My final solution to this was,  i downloaded OpenCV version 2.4.11 and reinstalled to my project. Now all works fines:

```
public  MainActivity()
        {
            if (!OpenCVLoader.InitDebug())
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Failed to INIT \n OpenCV Failure");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("OpenCV INIT Success");
            }
        }
```

Try this way it should definitely work.

Comment: thanks for your response. by adding these lines app crashing solved, but now there is another problem with openCv manager thats not found and not found in google play.

Comment: @SadeQdigitALLife could you please add the error you're receiving in the question you've asked stating 'updated code'

Comment: I have wrote error text in my question. here is:
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()J

Comment: Hi @SadeQdigitALLife check above answer, i've updated it for you with whatever i've tried to resolve this issue. Hope this get sorted now.